# When I run my flutter app in simulator it throw error but when I run it from Xcode it run without error - Mac

Tags: macos, iphone, xcode, android-studio

When I run my flutter app in simulator it throw error but when I run it from Xcode it run without error I don't know how it happen is it my machine issue or it's cocoapods issue

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Comment: Have you installed CocoaPods like it's telling you to do? `sudo gem install cocoapods` You can check if gem is installed by doing `gem --version`. If gem is not installed, you need to install Ruby. This can be easily done if you have homebrew with `brew install ruby`

Comment: I already have CocoaPods and it only happen when I run my app with android studio it work perfectly fine with xcode

Comment: Possible dupe on SO: [Flutter - Warning (CocoaPods not installed Skipping pod install) Even While Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68446186/2821954)

Comment: No this one also not help me!